# html2canvas not rendering SVG chart generated by CHARTIST.JS

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas, chartist.js

I have a page like this
[image: Chartist Chart]

I am trying to export this in a PDF by using html2canvas & jspdf.
After converting this chart section into canvas using html2canvas it looks like this.

[image: Totally blank, Only HTML have renderd]

Please help what should I do.

[image]

[image]

After using dom-to-image
[image: Error for dom to image]

Comment: Add the code you tried and try creating demo, look at [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
//id holds id of wrapper 'div' element which has child as svg graph (your chartist.js graph getting generated)

convertSVG(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    html2canvas(element, {useCORS: true, dpi: 144}).then(function(canvas) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');;
      element.append(img);
      img.onload = function () {
        console.log('I believe, your svg has converted to image');
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(img, 0, 0, doc.internal.pageSize.width, doc.internal.pageSize.height);
        doc.save("test.pdf")
      };
    });
  }
```

If still have the same problem, then chart may have line which html2canvas fails to consider.

Alternative HTML Rasterizing plugin : dom-to-html

`npm i dom-to-image`

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
.
.
.
ConvertSvgGraph(doc){
    let self = this;
    let element = self.SVGnodes[self.index];
    if (!element) {
      self.index++;
      return;
    }
    domtoimage.toPng(element)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      img.onload = function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(img, 0, 0, doc.internal.pageSize.width, doc.internal.pageSize.height);
        doc.save("test.pdf")
     }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Not working. Please check my question once more I have attached new screenshots.

Comment: what does your svg chart has? like path? or line? because with html2canvas conversion, line element is not considered as per my observation. Hence i have to use different library (dom-to-html). can you give a try with different html to png conversion library? let me know your results

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the SVG chart has line.

Comment: Have you tried alternative plugin which i mentioned?

Comment: updated my answer, update me once you see any result